# How to make some property of zod schame optional

Tags: typescript, interface, schema, zod

```js
const schema = z.object({
    id: z.string(),
    name: z.string(),
});
```

its equivalent with

```js
type schema = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

my question is, i have to make some properties optional but keep the type like this

```js
type schema = {
    id?: string;
    name: string;
}
```

if i use `.optional()`, it will make all properties optional

The purpose is, I need the `schema` for return from an database so the `id` is not null pk.

The case: I have upsert method

```js
// Insert value not working
const schemaInput = schema.parse({ name: 'My Name' });

// Update value is working
const schemaInput = schema.parse({ id: '123', name: 'My Name' });

user.upsert({ ...schemaInput, id: schemaInput?.id || generateId() })
```

But every time I execute the method, zod parser always showing an error

```
{
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "id"
    ],
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you using `.optional()` that makes it "make all properties optional"?

Answer (score 3):

You just make the value of that one property optional. Zod will notice this when that value is used as an object property and make that property optional for you.

```
const schema = z.object({
    id: z.string(),
    name: z.string().optional(),
});

const value = schema.parse({ name: 'abc' })
// value has type { id: string, name?: string | undefined }
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false&ts=4.9.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgFBkDGEAdgM7x2UAWApiAIZwC8KAdBABGAK1aUYACgRk4suMGIAufgyjAaAcwkBKADQy5NDiFbLkfVeq3aBYGMFocANjv1ptAbgrV68AG7OAK6sPHBMbJx8YBxQdKxS8koEHIKU+OjaZAD0WXIAegD8QA)

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I this I missed some information on my question. I already update the question.

Comment: Using `.optional()` on a property works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-lichterman-55ier7?file=/src/index.ts what am I missing? How is your code different?

Comment: Yes, in some cases using `.optional()` is working.
but here's what i need https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-tom-spmq7j?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Ahh I think i will close this question, i found the solution

just use `.partial({id:true})` so, the id will become optional
this can also multiple properties `.partial({propA:true, propB:true, propC: true})` and the rest of it will keep their own type.
if you want make them all optional, use `.partial()`